# How to fill the gaps in an image after thinning?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-morphology, line-drawing

How can I fill the gaps that occurred as a result of thinning? The first image is the image before thinning, the second one is the image after thinning and the third one is an example of the pixels that I need to connect. I'm using MATLAB R2013a.

I used this code in thinning:

```
bw_clean = imopen(binary_image, strel('rectangle',[3 3]));
bw_clean = bwareaopen(bw_clean, 15);
thin_image = ~bwmorph(imcomplement(bw_clean), 'thin', Inf);
```

Image before thinning:

[image: Image before thinning]

Image after thinning:

[image: Image after thinning]

Example of what I need to connect:

[image: Example of what I need to connect]

When I used `BW2 = imfill(A,'holes');` the output was:

[image: Output using imfill]

And when I used

```
se = strel('disk',10);
closeBW = imclose(A,se);
```

the output was:

[image: Output usimg imclose]

Comment: How did you perform the thinning? Did you use morphological operators? Perhaps the thinning process can be configured in a way that would create continuous lines. It would help if you could [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: If you compute the skeleton operation in the first image you will directly get what you want

Comment: @Dev-iL I edited the question and wrote the code I used in thinning.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Is that what you mean?

thin_image = ~bwmorph(imcomplement(bw_clean), 'skel', Inf);

Comment: This is not a thinning. Thinning respects the connectivity.

Comment: What you are seeing is caused by the image display. It is not showing all pixels in the image because it scaled it down to fit the image in the display area. Try zooming in on those regions you marked, you’ll see the missing pixels reappear.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: you are right, otherwise filling would have failed.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.